# Open another app with overlay view on it in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, widget, overlay

I am in big problem.
I want to open an app from mine app and when other app opened i want to overlay view over that app and in that view there is timer and button to go back to app.
I find some packages but no any docs for that like react native overlay and react native floating widget